# Android: Open webview's link in another activity contains webview

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I developed a simple android app contains WebView, how if I want open the links inside WebView1 in another activity contains WebView2?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I meant if the user click on any link inside WebView #1 (Activity1) it should open in WebView #2 (activity 2) not in WebView 1

Comment: there is library which will help you to achieve this. https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs

Comment: it's used to communicate between webview and native code